# Transversality of Slodowy-type slice

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nilpotent-orbits

Let $x$ be a nilpotent element in $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{gl}_n$ and $y$ some arbitrary element in $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $Z_\mathfrak{g}(x)$ be the centralizer of $x$ in $\mathfrak{g}$ and consider the affine space $y+Z_\mathfrak{g}(x)$. I'd like to understand the intersection of this affine space with the nilpotent cone $\mathcal{N}$, specifically its dimension. When $y$ is nilpotent and forms an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ triple with $x$ and some semisimple $h$, this is exactly the Slodowy slice and the intersection is transverse and has the expected dimension.

But this condition on $y$ seems quite restrictive, and I would like to understand how crucial it is. For example, for the case I am really interested in, suppose we do away with the nilpotency of $y$, but do assume that the commutator $[x,y]$ satisfies that $[x,y]+I$ has rank 1, (and thus, $[x,y]$ is semisimple). Can we say something about the intersection of the affine slice with the nilpotent cone in this case?

Comment: I think the condition on $y$ is impossible unless $x$ is a regular nilpotent element. Certainly, if we assume $[x, y]$ is diagonal and of rank 1 then we might as well assume $y\in {\mathfrak g}(-2,h)$. Then it's easy to see that $[x, y] +I$ has rank $\geq 2$ unless $x$ is a single Jordan block.

Comment: @PaulLevy $[x,y]$ need not have rank 1, only $[x,y]+I$ does.

Comment: Despite my typo, I'm still fairly sure that $[x,y]+I$ has to have rank greater than 1 unless $x$ is a single Jordan block.

Comment: Take $x=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{pmatrix}0&-3&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\1&-1&3&0\\1&0&1&3\end{pmatrix}$. Then, $[x,y]+I$ has rank 1.